# How to dispay two different graphs one below other using same input dataset in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm trying to have two graphs in the same tab in flexdashboard. The two have the same input variable and should be selected by user but the output should be independent. I would like to have a choice to display one graph alone or the two together.

I found some resource for shiny but I've been struggling to implement them in my code. I'm providing an example of my code so far:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---


```{r}
df <- data.frame(
  frequency = c(22,23,24,25,26,27),
  transmission = c(91,92,93,94,95,96),
  replicate = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)),
  power = c(20, 0, 5, 6, 40, 60)
)
```

```{r}
library("tidyverse")
library("xts")
library("fs")
library("plotly")
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("shinyjs")
library("shinydashboard")
library("flexdashboard")
```


Acoustic Power output
=================================
  
  Sidebar{.sidebar data-width=400} 
---------------------------------
  
  **Exploring the acoustic data output**
  
  This is an interactive dashboard to facilitate analysis of power measurements


<br>
  
  **Scatterplot**
  
Choose the variables to be displayed. 

```{r inputs_1, echo=FALSE}
# Inputs for all axis
selectInput(inputId = "x",
            label = "X-Axis",
            choices = names(df))
selectInput(inputId = "y",
            label = "Y-Axis",
            choices = names(df))
selectInput(inputId = "z",
            label = "Colour by",
            choices = names(df))


minvalue <- floor(min(df$frequency))
maxvalue <- ceiling(max(df$frequency))

sliderInput(
  inputId ="freq_range",
  label = "Select frequency range",
  min = minvalue,
  max = maxvalue,
  value = c(minvalue, maxvalue)
)
```

**Single plots**
This can be used to display single plots and directly compare the output

```{r inputs_2, echo=FALSE}

# Picker Input Widget: PICK TRANSDUCER

shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
  inputId  = "pick_replicate",
  label    = "Pick replicates ",
  choices  = sort(unique(df$replicate)),
  selected = unique(df$replicate),
  multiple = TRUE # Allow multiple option
)
# Picker Input Widget: PICK REPLICATE


shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
  inputId = "graph_select",
  label = "Select graph", 
  choices = c("Graph 1", "Graph 2"),
  multiple = TRUE
  )


# Action button
actionButton(inputId = "apply", 
             label   = "Apply", 
             icon    = icon("play"),
             width   = '50%')
# Reset button
actionButton(inputId = "reset",
             label = "Reset",
             icon = icon("sync"),
            width   = '50%')

# Apply buttons
# 
observeEvent(eventExpr = input$reset,# When button is clicked..
             handlerExpr = { # ...this is executed
               # Update picker widget: Transducer
               updatePickerInput(
                 session = session,
                 inputId = "pick_replicate",
                 selected = unique(df$replicate)
               )
              # Update picker widget: Replicate
             updatePickerInput(
                 session = session,
                 inputId = "graph_select",
                 selected = ""
               )
             #   
               # Delay and Mimic click on Apply button
               shinyjs::delay(ms = 300, expr = {
                 shinyjs::click(id = "apply")
               })
             })
```


<br>

Row {.tabset}
-------------------------------------------

### Scatter plot

```{r, echo = F}
# Reactive Event: waits until a button (Apply) is clicked to run reactive code

filtered_df_grap2 <- eventReactive(
  eventExpr = "Graph 2" %in% input$graph_select, 
  valueExpr = {
    df %>%
    filter(replicate %in% input$pick_replicate) %>% 
    filter(frequency >= input$freq_range[1] & frequency <= input$freq_range[2])
  }
)

```

```{r,message = FALSE,echo = FALSE}
output$plotly_1 <- renderPlotly({
  filtered_df_grap2() %>%
 ggplot(aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y,
                    colour = input$z))+
    geom_point()+
    theme_classic()
})
plotlyOutput(outputId= "plotly_1")

```


Row {.tabset}
-------------------------------------------

```{r, echo = F}
# Reactive Event: waits until a button (Apply) is clicked to run reactive code

filtered_df_grap1 <- eventReactive(
  eventExpr = "Graph 1" %in% input$graph_select,
  valueExpr = {
    df %>%
    filter(replicate %in% input$pick_replicate) %>% 
    filter(frequency >= input$freq_range[1] & frequency <= input$freq_range[2])
  }
)

```
```{r,message = FALSE,echo = FALSE}
output$plotly_2 <- renderPlotly({
  filtered_df_grap1() %>%
  ggplot(aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y,
                    colour = input$z))+
    geom_point()+
    theme_classic()
})
plotlyOutput(outputId= "plotly_2")

```
````

Any suggestion are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this. One method is to use `Column` and set the `data-width`. (You don't need `Row` at all.)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---


```{r}
df <- data.frame(
  frequency = c(22,23,24,25,26,27),
  transmission = c(91,92,93,94,95,96),
  replicate = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)),
  power = c(20, 0, 5, 6, 40, 60)
)
```

```{r}
library("tidyverse")
library("xts")
library("fs")
library("plotly")
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("shinyjs")
library("shinydashboard")
library("flexdashboard")
```


Acoustic Power output
=================================
  
  Sidebar{.sidebar data-width=400} 
---------------------------------
  
  **Exploring the acoustic data output**
  
  This is an interactive dashboard to facilitate analysis of power measurements


<br>
  
  **Scatterplot**
  
Choose the variables to be displayed. 

```{r inputs_1, echo=FALSE}
# Inputs for all axis
selectInput(inputId = "x",
            label = "X-Axis",
            choices = names(df))
selectInput(inputId = "y",
            label = "Y-Axis",
            choices = names(df))
selectInput(inputId = "z",
            label = "Colour by",
            choices = names(df))


minvalue <- floor(min(df$frequency))
maxvalue <- ceiling(max(df$frequency))

sliderInput(
  inputId ="freq_range",
  label = "Select frequency range",
  min = minvalue,
  max = maxvalue,
  value = c(minvalue, maxvalue)
)
```

**Single plots**
This can be used to display single plots and directly compare the output

```{r inputs_2, echo=FALSE}

# Picker Input Widget: PICK TRANSDUCER

shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
  inputId  = "pick_replicate",
  label    = "Pick replicates ",
  choices  = sort(unique(df$replicate)),
  selected = unique(df$replicate),
  multiple = TRUE # Allow multiple option
)
# Picker Input Widget: PICK REPLICATE


shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
  inputId = "graph_select",
  label = "Select graph", 
  choices = c("Graph 1", "Graph 2"),
  multiple = TRUE
  )


# Action button
actionButton(inputId = "apply", 
             label   = "Apply", 
             icon    = icon("play"),
             width   = '50%')
# Reset button
actionButton(inputId = "reset",
             label = "Reset",
             icon = icon("sync"),
            width   = '50%')

# Apply buttons
# 
observeEvent(eventExpr = input$reset,# When button is clicked..
             handlerExpr = { # ...this is executed
               # Update picker widget: Transducer
               updatePickerInput(
                 session = session,
                 inputId = "pick_replicate",
                 selected = unique(df$replicate)
               )
              # Update picker widget: Replicate
             updatePickerInput(
                 session = session,
                 inputId = "graph_select",
                 selected = ""
               )
             #   
               # Delay and Mimic click on Apply button
               shinyjs::delay(ms = 300, expr = {
                 shinyjs::click(id = "apply")
               })
             })
```


<br>

Column {data-width=1000}
-------------------------------------------

### Scatter plot

```{r, echo = F}
# Reactive Event: waits until a button (Apply) is clicked to run reactive code

filtered_df_grap2 <- eventReactive(
  eventExpr = "Graph 2" %in% input$graph_select, 
  valueExpr = {
    df %>%
    filter(replicate %in% input$pick_replicate) %>% 
    filter(frequency >= input$freq_range[1] & frequency <= input$freq_range[2])
  }
)

```


```{r,message = FALSE,echo = FALSE}
output$plotly_1 <- renderPlotly({
  filtered_df_grap2() %>%
 ggplot(aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y,
                    colour = input$z))+
    geom_point()+
    theme_classic()
})
plotlyOutput(outputId= "plotly_1", width = "100%", height = "50%")

```

### Scatter plot

```{r, echo = F}
# Reactive Event: waits until a button (Apply) is clicked to run reactive code

filtered_df_grap1 <- eventReactive(
  eventExpr = "Graph 1" %in% input$graph_select,
  valueExpr = {
    df %>%
    filter(replicate %in% input$pick_replicate) %>% 
    filter(frequency >= input$freq_range[1] & frequency <= input$freq_range[2])
  }
)

```



```{r,message = FALSE,echo = FALSE}
output$plotly_2 <- renderPlotly({
  filtered_df_grap1() %>%
  ggplot(aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y,
                    colour = input$z)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_classic()
})
plotlyOutput(outputId= "plotly_2", width = "100%", height = "50%")

```
````

[image]

Comment: Hi, that displays the two graphs but the input (x,y, colour) cannot be different between the two. I would like to be able to select different inputs and show different things in the two. Do you have a suggestion here? Thanks!